# Manga about a MC and his wife Haru who train knights and take a wolf as a pet

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

There was a manga in which the MC has a wife named Haru and they both train the knights after defeating a wolf which later the MC and his wife takes as a pet. Also, the demon king intrigued after knowing that his people are dying due to an unknown person living in the forest goes to investigate and in turn becomes friends with the MC. The hero summoned by the king has a level 999 but cannot go further than that and ends up getting sucked up by a cursed jar in the treasury of the kingdom.

Comment: This is a nice start but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] it? For example, do you know when you read this?

Answer (score 3):

[Ex-Hero Candidate's, Who Turned Out To Be A Cheat From Lv2](https://www.readmng.com/lv2-kara-cheat-datta-moto-yuusha-kouho-no-mattari-isekai-life) is similar enough that I feel it might be the answer, but has enough differences that I am not certain.

> MC has a wife named Haru and they both train the knights after defeating a wolf which later the MC and his wife takes as a pet.  The two of them train an adventuring party of a knight, heavy knight, witch, and archer by having them fight the pet bear.

The main character defeats a wolf who transforms into a woman and becomes his wife. Her name is not Haru though.  Together they later defeat a group of bears and make one of them their pet.

> Also, the demon king intrigued after knowing that his people are dying due to an unknown person living in the forest goes to investigate and in turn becomes friends with the MC.

Purification magic was used by the main character, which wiped out the demons in the forest. A demon, the wolf who was mentioned above, then went to investigate what happened and became more than friends with them. The demon king sent a demon out to investigate after that, who just found the group in the last chapter i read.

> The hero summoned by the king has a level 999 but cannot go further than that and ends up getting sucked up by a cursed jar in the treasury of the kingdom.

The hero, not the main character, is summoned with all their stats at 999, but was only level 1.  Later we see he leveled up, but his stats stayed the same. I did not see anything about him being sucked into a cursed jar, but there does appear to be a light novel which is further along in the story.  I haven't read it, but that point could be in there.